# Thévenin Equivalent in a Circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

I came up with the following problem that asks to find the Thévenin equivalent of the circuit below. However in the manual solution, I found that the author uses 1A for the a to b branch, and I have no idea with my current knowledge of circuit analysis of this event. I'd like very much any explanation of this topic.

[image]

Comment: It's called a test source. Author probably used it to simplify the calculations.

Comment: Yes, I think it's a good motif, but why not to use another value?

Comment: 1 A is quite nice, simple integer value to work with, compared to other values. You could use any other value if you like.

Comment: @JoãoVíctorMelo Yes, the reason is simple. The change in voltage is the same value as the resistance when you use 1 A. Otherwise, you have to go get a calculator and do a division, which is kind of pointless when you might have just used a 1 A source and be done with the problem, already. ;)